# How to make a section of code start first-Java Small error/last little step

Tags: java, actionlistener

So the task I've been set is to make an animation of a lamp. There are buttons added that do different actions such as change colour of the sphere etc.

Code: Sphere Class

```
 public class Sphere extends JPanel {
private boolean flashinglights = false;
private int x = 168;
private int y = 75;
private Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.ORANGE, Color.LIGHT_GRAY };
private int colorIndex = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (!flashinglights) {


        Rectangle box0 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+50,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box0);
        g3.fill(box0);

        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+90,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box1);
        g3.fill(box1);

        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+130,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box2);
        g3.fill(box2);

        Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+170,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box3);
        g3.fill(box3);


        Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+210,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box4);
        g3.fill(box4);

        Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+250,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box5);
        g3.fill(box5);

        Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+290,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box6);
        g3.fill(box6);

        Rectangle box7 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+330,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box7);
        g3.fill(box7);

        Rectangle box8 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+370,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box8);
        g3.fill(box8);


        Rectangle box9 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+410,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box9);
        g3.fill(box9);

        Rectangle box10 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+450,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box10);
        g3.fill(box10);


        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 50, 50);
        g2.draw(ball);
        g2.fill(ball);
    } else {
        if(colorIndex > colors.length - 1)
            colorIndex = 0;

        Rectangle box0 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+50,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box0);
        g3.fill(box0);

        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+90,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box1);
        g3.fill(box1);

        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+130,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box2);
        g3.fill(box2);

        Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+170,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box3);
        g3.fill(box3);


        Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+210,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box4);
        g3.fill(box4);

        Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+250,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box5);
        g3.fill(box5);

        Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+290,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box6);
        g3.fill(box6);

        Rectangle box7 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+330,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box7);
        g3.fill(box7);

        Rectangle box8 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+370,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box8);
        g3.fill(box8);


        Rectangle box9 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+410,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        g3.draw(box9);
        g3.fill(box9);

        Rectangle box10 = new Rectangle(x+16, y+450,14, 50);
        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.draw(box10);
        g3.fill(box10);

        g2.setColor(colors[colorIndex++]);
         Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 50, 50);
        g2.draw(ball);
        g2.fill(ball);
    }
}

public void chooseflashinglights(){
    flashinglights = true;
}

public void choosesteady(){
    flashinglights = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame scFrame = new AnimationViewer();
    scFrame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
    scFrame.setSize(400, 500);
    scFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation((JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));
    scFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Code: Animation Viewer CLass

```
public class AnimationViewer extends JFrame {
JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
Sphere sphPanel = new Sphere();
Timer timer;

public AnimationViewer() {
    timer = new Timer(500, new TimerListener());
    this.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    bPanel.add(jbtFlash);
    bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    bPanel.add(jbtSteady);

    this.add(sphPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sphPanel.chooseflashinglights();
            timer.start();
        }
    });

       jbtSteady.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sphPanel.choosesteady();
            timer.stop();
            sphPanel.repaint();
        }
    });

}

class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sphPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

}

The main two buttons do two different things. One makes the sphere stay a solid orange colour (Steady) and the other makes the sphere alternate from Orange to grey. (flashing)

**NOW THE PROBLEM:**
When you start the program the sphere starts of in Steady mode were the colour is just solid orange.

I want the program to START in flashing mode. So when you click run the sphere should be straight in the flashing stage alternating from orange to grey straight away.

So how can I make it so I can start a piece of code first so it goes straight to the flashing lights mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the code used to switch the mode to flashing in a method, to avoid code duplication:

```
private void flash() {
    sphPanel.chooseflashinglights();
    timer.start();
}
```

Call this method from the action listener:

```
jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        flash();
    }
});
```

And also call it in the constructor:

```
public AnimationViewer() {
    // existing code omitted

    flash();
}
```